# Have to Click Form To Give Focus

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a main form with buttons that open a custom message box form. It works fine if it's just a message and the user just needs to click OK. But if the answer to that message box is important, like "Are you sure you want to delete this file?" I use a while loop to wait for the user to respond and once they do then a flag is set from false to true and the response is recorded.

For some reason any response that uses a while loop to wait is causing the message box form to not have focus after being called. Requiring the user to first click on the form, and then click on OK.

So far I've tried using `form.Activate()` instead of `form.Show()`, as well as calling `Application.DoEvents()` inside the while loop since I believed the while loop was taking focus away from the message form immediately after being called. Neither solved the issue.

Code from a message box that works as intended:

```
If cmbLoadProgram.SelectedItem = "" Then
    frmMessageBox.lblHeader.Text = "Set-Up"
    frmMessageBox.lblMessageText.Text = "No Program Selected!"
    frmMessageBox.Show()
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Code from a message box that needs to be clicked twice:

```
If btnGetHexStart.Visible = False And cmbStartCondition.SelectedItem = "Pixel" Then
    frmMessageBox.lblHeader.Text = "Hex Set-Up"
    frmMessageBox.lblMessageText.Text = "Reset Hex Code Data?"
    frmMessageBox.Show()
    Me.Hide()
        While Flag = False
            If frmMain.OKCancel = "OK" Then
                btnGetHexStart.Visible = True
                btnGetHexStart.Enabled = True
                btnGetHexStart.PerformClick()
                Flag = True
            End If
        frmMain.delay(20)
        End While
End If
```

I'm wanting both options to only need to be clicked once in order to confirm or cancel the action. Instead of the while loop questions needing to be clicked twice.

Comment: The whole premise here is just crazy.  You should simply be calling `ShowDialog` on the message form in the first place.  When the modal dialogue is closed, the caller will automatically be refocused.

Comment: Do you have any reason to use frmMessageBox that you created rather than use MessageBox that vb.net has?

Comment: @user11982798 The VB message box sucks and my program is custom with different font and colors, its customized. Going from that to an ugly looking message box looks unprofessional.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I tried just setting the buttons and the form to dialog results and using showdialog but it didnt work. I'll try it again and post a new question about that issue. It would be a lot better if I did that but this was my workaround since I couldn't figure out why it wasn't recording responses.

Comment: *"I'll try it again and post a new question about that issue"*.  That sounds like a good plan.  It certainly should work that way.  You could even create a custom class that mimics the `MessageBox` functionality, i.e. you call a `Shared` method and it creates a form and displays it internally.

Comment: @jmcilhinney well I have no idea why but using `ShowDialog` works perfectly fine now. I must've been tired and did something wrong or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just an idea from me, just how to open msgboxform, here we need MessageForm and one module1, for example:

```
Public Class MessageForm
    'You can assign any variable to show any data in messageform display
    Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        theResult = MsgBoxResult.Ok
        Me.Close()
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bttcancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bttcancel.Click
        theResult = MsgBoxResult.Cancel
        Me.Close()
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1
    Public theResult As MsgBoxResult

    'You can add some parameter here to submit to MessageForm
    Public Function myMessageBox() As MsgBoxResult
        myMessageBox = MsgBoxResult.Cancel
        MessageForm.ShowDialog()
        myMessageBox = theResult
    End Function
End Module
```

and then you can call the myMessageBox anywhere like this:

```
'if myMessageBox procedure have parameter, apply the paramters too
dim myRslt = myMessageBox()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a form,You can use DialogResult and MessageBox.Show, code:

```
  Dim Result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Set-Up" & vbCrLf & "No Program Selected!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)

    If Result = DialogResult.OK Then

    ElseIf Result = DialogResult.Cancel Then

    End If
```

Comment: I know about the message box and input box. My form is customized with different fonts, colors, borders, etc. The transition from my custom form to the default messagebox is jarring and looks unprofessional. I wanted a custom message box form that I could alter to match the style of my regular form.